# Using firebase admin node.js SDK via edge.js (c#)

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, firebase-admin, edge.js

I have web service that writing in C# , and host in azure .
As part of my processing I want to use the fire-base admin via my C# code.
After I looking in the web I found the edge.js package that let you to run node.js scripts under C# , I install the package and success to run different node.js scripts via C# .
The problem start when I try to use the firebase admin SDK .
I install the firebase lib via npm (`npm install firebase-admin -g`) as global package. 
Then I try to use it for calling the firebase lib , I try only to load the lib and I received error.

```
 var func = Edge.Func(@"

return function(data,callback)
{
var admin = require('firebase - admin');
callback(null, 'test fcm ' + data);
}

");
```

The error I received in c# is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

So I have several question :
1. May someone success to work with the fire-base lib via edge.js  ?

2. How I can debug the error ?
3. May someone have different method for calling the firebase admin nodejs sdk via C# ?
4. May someone have any method for calling the firebase admin via C# code ?

Thanks ,
MAK

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, you'd need to run the command `npm install firebase-admin` in the root of your c# project, it will install the dependencies in the `node_modules` folder for your project.

You also need to remove spaces from the package name as below:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
```